# Trouble using Watir to click a tab on a page

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I am trying to click the second tab `Tab1_imgImbillsTab`.

```
<div id="menuTabsForPageContainer" >
<div id="menuTabsForPage">
    <img id="Tab1_imgHomePageTab" accesskey="H" disabled="disabled" class="imgHomePageTab" src="images/home_deselected_tab.png" alt="Home" style="border-width:0px;" />
    <img id="Tab1_imgImbillsTab" accesskey="B" class="imgImbillsTab" src="images/bills_deselected_tab.png" alt="Bills" style="border-width:0px;" />    
    <img id="Tab1_imgArchiveTab" accesskey="C" class="imgArchiveTab" src="images/chartrack_deselected_tab.png" alt="Chart Rack" style="border-width:0px;" />
    <img id="Tab1_imgPracMgmtTab" accesskey="I" class="imgPracMgmtTab" src="images/managementreporting_deselected_tab.png" alt="Business Intelligence" style="border-width:0px;" />
    <img id="Tab1_imgSysToolTab" accesskey="Y" class="imgSysToolTab" src="images/systemtools_deselected_tab.png" alt="System Tools" style="border-width:0px;" />       
    <img id="Tab1_imgBulletinTab" accesskey="S" class="imgBulletinTab" src="images/settings_deselected_tab.png" alt="Settings" style="border-width:0px;" />     
</div>
</div>
```

I tried several things:

```
browser.button(:id => 'Tab1_imgImbillsTab').click
browser.div(:id, "menuTabsForPage").div(:id, "menuTabsForPage").button(:id, "Tab1_imgImbillsTab").click
```

I also tried to reference it as a clickable image by referencing the "src" of the image.  These tabs, I believe have JavaSceript behind them.  I can not figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: if the tabs have JS behind them, did you show the original markup, or is this the generated source?

Comment: I may not understand your question.  I got this html from "view source" in the browser, so I presume that is generated source?

Comment: When you view source, browsers will generally display what is currently being rendered on the page, which means the source reflects any changes the JavaScript has caused. Instead, either turn off JavaScript in the browser then load the page, then view the source, or, better, use something like `curl`, `wget` or some other tool and directly download the page to a file and then view it in your text editor.

Comment: When you are referencing HTML from a site, it's essential that you show us the HTML you are talking about in the question, which you did. Thank you. In addition, it'd help if you also supplied the URL to the page so we can confirm/test ideas we have that involve the whole page. Also, salutations ("Greetings") and valedictions ("Any help is appreciated!") are not necessary nor are they desired. Consider Stack Overflow to be a reference book, except it's a little bit less formal.

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
browser.button(:id => 'Tab1_imgImbillsTab').click
```

Says to find a `button` element or `input` element (of type button, reset, submit or image) that has the `id` "Tab1_imgImbillsTab".

However, based on the HTML, the tab is an `img` tag. As a result, it will never be found by the `button` method. Tell Watir to look for the `img` tag instead:

```
browser.img(:id => 'Tab1_imgImbillsTab').click
```